# How do I reference the row I had just inserted into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this function in a Code Igniter model that creates a new "video."

```
// Creates a new video.
public function newVideo($title, $description) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO videos VALUES (NULL, '$title', '$description')");
    return // id of this new row
}
```

How do I obtain the ID of this new row in my MySQL table? I could get the last row and add 1, but there could be concurrency bugs I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple answer doesn't really need more than 30 chars does it?

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this answer here too (http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/63052/). Is it concurrent-proof?

Comment: Yes, getting the insert_id from your db module is the only safe way that I am aware of. Methods like the longer solution provided here have gotten me into DB trainwrecks in the past!

Answer (score 5):

maybe you need something like this

```
    $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: it will return the last insert row id

Comment: Thanks, I saw this answer here too (http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/63052/). Is it concurrent-proof?

Comment: Voting for Joni's matching solution - His was here 30 sec before mine!

Comment: ,well im just answering a question here, i dont mean that well have the same

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```
$lastID = -1; //That's where it'll be stored

$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) 
{
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
     $lastID = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: This is asking for concurrency issues, isn't it? using the DB object's insert_id will guarantee you the id of the row that you just inserted.

Comment: Well, just noticed it has been tagged with `codeigniter`. My answer is generally valid, but probably not the shortest one in that case...

Comment: Any time you use LAST_INSERT_ID(), you will get the very latest id from your table. If two people run your script at the same time, it's very possible you will get the ID of the row inserted by the other script.

Comment: Yes, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works on a per-connection basis. If your application is using a threadpool to connect to MySQL, this may lead to getting wrong ids.

Answer (score 1):

Code for an insert is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO videos (title) VALUES(NULL, '$title', '$description')";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

More information on queries available at: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is that you can have a look into videos table in your database, and make you video id as autonumber, this will automatically generate an id for your video and then you can try this:

```
//on your model
$sql = "INSERT INTO videos (title,description) VALUES('$title', '$description')";
$this->db->query($sql);

//retrieve new video id
$this->db->insert_id()
```