# Can I get columns of last inserted row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hi I'm using Codeigniter and would love a solution in CI but can suffice with mysqli or PDO.

I was wondering if there is a way to get a column of the last inserted row in MySql 5.1.54

The reason is I'm inserting a null value which then a trigger changes that null into some calculated value and instead of getting the last inserted id and querying for that value.

Is there some way this can be done?

**In case I wasn't clear : I know I can run a query on last inserted id, I mean can I get last inserted "column"?**

Comment: By retrieving the last inserted Id and then doing a select

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832461/how-do-i-reference-the-row-i-had-just-inserted-into-a-mysql-table?rq=1

Comment: I know that, i asked if i can column of last inserted id without running another query, i thought i was clear in the qustion...

Comment: No, you can't. You'll have to run another query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess the answer @Eric is looking for is NO.

Comment: Yep that's answer... it's possible in Oracle and it sounds logicall that some driver make it possible if you assign an index or something.

Comment: do you mean `RETURNING` with expression in Oracle? it seems that stored proc can be the best solution in MySql in terms of speed, not sure how testable or maintainable though.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last inserted id by

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

and select the last row and use it normally

ref [Query Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: I know that, i asked if i can column of last inserted id without running another query

Answer (score 0):

The PDO comes with [lastInsertId method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). You can then `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=return_of_this_function`.

Comment: I know that, i asked if i can column of last inserted id without running another query